# Unir dos arreglos de 1 en 1

Tags: javascript, array

Este ejercicio pide recibir dos arreglos como parámetro y unirlos de a 1.
Por ej: `([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` y retornar `[1,'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c']`.

El problema es que al intentar fusionarlos repite el indice del 1er arreglo la cantidad del 2do.
Espero que se entienda y puedan ayudarme a encontrar la falla.

Este es mi código:

```js
function arregloUnido(arr1, arr2) {

  let arrFinal = []
  for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      arrFinal.push(arr1[i])
      arrFinal.push(arr2[j])
    }
  }
  return arrFinal
}

console.log(arregloUnido([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour]. Ademas si alguna respuesta solución tu problema, por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que estás usando dos ciclos, cuando solo necesitas uno, donde agregues directamente los dos elementos de cada arreglo.

Si los dos arreglos siempre van a tener la misma cantidad de elementos, agregas ambos en cada iteración del ciclo. Si pueden tener diferente cantidad solo compruebas que exista.

```js
function arregloUnido(arr1, arr2) {

  let arrFinal = [];
  // Suponiendo que los arreglos no sean simétricos
  let max = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length);
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      // En cada iteración se agrega un elemento de cada arreglo
      // Solo si existe el elemento
      if(typeof arr1[i] != 'undefined') {
          arrFinal.push(arr1[i]);
      }
      if(typeof arr2[i] != 'undefined') {
          arrFinal.push(arr2[i]);
      }
  }
  return arrFinal;
}

// Arreglos simétricos
console.log(arregloUnido([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']));
// No simétricos
console.log(arregloUnido([9, 8, 7], ['z', 'y', 'x', 'w']));
```

Comment: Seria bueno explicarle al OP cual ha sido su error y despues darle la solucion

Comment: @JuanRivera, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas!
Triby, super claro! gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción es usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), recorriendo el segundo array y agregando los elementos de ambos arrays al array final

```js
function join(a1, a2) {
  const f = [];
  a2.forEach((el,i) => {
    f.push(el);
    if (a1[i] !== undefined) f.push(a1[i]);
  });
  return f;
}

console.log(join(["a","b","c"],[1,2,3]));
```

Se sabe que un índice inexistente en un array, dará `undefined` como elemento, por lo cual simplemente comprobamos que `a1[i]` no sea `undefined`

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, sobre todo porque puede resultar más sencillo que un ciclo for. Tal vez puedas mejorarla, dejándola solo para arreglos simétricos, así OP tendrá un par de opciones para elegir la que mejor le acomode. Por cierto, también sería buena idea no invertir el orden de los argumentos, generalmente este tipo de preguntas son para resolver ejercicios y esa modificación hará que no pase las pruebas.

Comment: `undefined` puede ser un valor de un arreglo, ej: `[1, undefined, 3]` por lo que es mejor revisar la longituddel arreglo

Answer (score 0):

Podrias ayudarte de un `flag` o una variable que te indique de arreglo debes obtener los datos y con esta misma variable revisar si el indice que estas evaluando tiene que aumentarse o no, una vez este flag se modifique aumentas el valor del inidice, con esto la solucion quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```js
function arregloUnido(arr1, arr2) {
    const final = []

    let idx = 0;
    let useFirst = false;

    while (idx != arr1.length) {
        useFirst = !useFirst;
        final.push(useFirst ? arr1[idx] : arr2[idx])

        if (!useFirst) {
            idx += 1;
        }
    }

    return final
}

const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

console.log(arregloUnido(a, b))
```